# HybridAuth - handling expired provider tokens during authentication

Tags: php, exception, oauth, single-sign-on, hybridauth

The HybridAuth documentation as many have noted is extremely lacking, so I'm having a hard time finding the proper method for dealing with Expired Tokens during an attempted Auth sequence.  My code is currently:

```
try {

    $provider = /* Provider Object in our system */

    // Initialize HybridAuth
    $client = new Hybrid_Auth($provider->get_config());

    // try to authenticate with the selected provider
    $adapter = $client->authenticate( $provider->name );

    // then grab the user profile
    /* @var $user_profile Hybrid_User_Profile */
    $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();

} catch( Exception $e ) {

    $user_profile = NULL;
    $adapter->logout();

}
```

If the session is still active at our end for whatever reason, but the token has expired at the provider, the line `$user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();` just prior to the `catch` is throwing an exception which is expected (*although the error messages are missing some very important info and are somewhat misleading*).

I was able to find in another thread (*which I'm sorry I can't find, please feel free to edit in a link if you know of an example*) that I need to instruct HybridAuth to forget the token info by using the `$adapter->logout();` method.

**So what now?  Am I supposed to redirect, if so, what address? What's the best practice here?**

Any insights would be gratefully appreciated!